# Proving a recurrence relation by induction $f(L) = f(L-1) +1 = L-1.$

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to prove inductively  that the recurrence  relation :

$f(L) = f(L-1)+1$ is equivalent to $g(L) = L-1$

with some following Base cases: $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 0$, $f(2) = 1.$  for the recurrence relation.

So far:
 $ L = 1$

$f(1) = 0$  because of the base case, and  $g(1) = 1 - 1 = 0 $ So it is TRUE at $L = 1$

$L = k$

$f(k) = f(k-1) + 1$ and $g(k) = k-1$

Comment: Include your working. Also, $f(0)=0$?

Comment: The recurrence relation has some base cases at 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: Only one base case is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$f(k) = k-1$,
then
$f(k+1)
=f(k)+1
=(k-1)+1
=k
=(k+1)-1
$
so it is true for
$k+1$.

Since it is true for
$k=1$,
it is true for
all $k \ge 1$.